# Can I share a different URL than mentioned in Facebook Meta og:url?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've a page at `http://www.example.com/sample/result/2` it has the following Facebook meta set

```
og:image = 'http://www.example.com/uploads/result2.png'

og:url = 'http://www.example.com/sample/result/2'
```

I want to share this page with a Facebook share button for: `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.example.com/sample" >`

I don't want the Facebook users to go to `/sample/result/2` page but use their meta only. Is that possible if I point og:url to `'http://www.example.com/sample/result/2'` but share `http://www.example.com/sample` instead?

Please guide me.

Comment: Why dont you point `og:url` to `/sample` instead?

Comment: @SahilMittal, then it will scrape `/sample` instead of `/sample/result/2` I want FB to show `/result2.png` for `result/2` and then `/result3.png` for `/result/3` and so on. That's why. :(

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/open-graph-object/)-

> An **Open Graph protocol URL** collapses the many URLs representing the same content into a single, *representative URL* to be shared using Open Graph. This behavior is similar to the canonical link relation used by major search engines.
>
> The presence of the above URL allows Facebook to collapse references to `/lamb?source=email` and `/lamb` into the same Open Graph object, aggregating Likes, Comments, and other actions to the specified `og:url` value.

But you are trying to use `og:url` in different/wrong perspective. So, I don't think its possible to separate out the link shared and `og:url` present in that link!